# Xamarin iOS app can't submit to TestFlight error ITMS-90700

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hoping for some assistance.  I have a Xamarin iOS project (Windows) which I'm trying to submit to TestFlight and getting the following error:

ERROR ITMS-90700: "Incorrect Platform. You included arm64 executable “iQ.Mobile.Safety.iOS.app/iQ.Mobile.Safety.iOS” in your iOS bundle. Only iOS executables can be included."

I have gone through the dependencies in Visual Studio and marked them all as x64 but I still get the same error.

Help appreciated.

Comment: In your info.plist file, what values do you have under UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities? And when you open the iOS project settings, under the "Supported Architectures" property on the iOS Build tab, what CPUs are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to share the picture through the comments. But when you open your binary in Xcode, does changing the Architecture to Arm64 fix the problem?

[image: Xcode image]

Comment: How do I do that when its an Visual Studio Xamarin project?  I didn't think it was possible?

Comment: Instead of using the Application Uploader, just save the signed IPA file to disk and open it in Xcode

Comment: I'm not sure this works? This is what I get https://imgur.com/a/HcAnqNT